# understanding angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular.JS version 1.1.5 and I am using the following code I found on stackoverflow to change the background-image of a div:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('ng-background', function(){
  return function(scope, element, attrs){
    var url = attrs['ng-background'];
    element.css({
      'background-image': 'url(' + url +')',
      'background-size' : 'cover'
    });
  };
});
```

Then, in my HTML, I have the following (jade template)

```
html(ng-app)
  div(ng-controller='myCtrl')
    div.big-image(ng-background='{{flags.imgSrc}}')
```

Now, please consider that flags.imgSrc does work and returns a correct image URL, as I have previously tested it with an `img(ng-src='{{flags.imgSrc}}')`.

The problem with this is that it does not seem to work at all! I have tried to put a `console.log('test')` inside my directive but it does not seem to called. Any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you need to rename your directive to `ngBackground` Angular converts **snake-case** to **camelCase** for your convenience.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
.directive('ngBackground')
```

HTML

```
div.big-image(ng-background='{{flags.imgSrc}}')
```

Normal Example

```
App.directive('myAmazingDirective');
```

HTML

```
<div my-amazing-directive></div>
```

Also you would have to get your attributes using **camelCase** as well so.

```
var url = attrs.ngBackground;
```

Comment: I cannot really see any convenience in that! thanks anyway! another thing, what about attrs['ng-background'] just inside the directive? should it be camelCased or snake-cased?

Comment: that's right maybe It's just that there's a bigger learning curve. Anyway, it still does not seem to work for me, any way to check it? I have added the console.log just before the return statement, is that correct? should it be called it everything was set right?

Comment: ok, got that. yea, the problem seems to be another one then... do you have 2 minutes in chat?

Comment: alright, got that. it seems to work if I insert the direct url, but it does not with something like ng-background="{{flags.imgSrc}}" which is pretty weird, it does with ng-src.... any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Your directive is likely never getting called. For a directive named "ng-background", I'm not even sure how you would call that. Normally the camel cased name of the directive is converted to the dashed name you use in your HTML.

To quote an example from AngularJS official documentation. They create a directive named myCurrentTime and call it via:

```
<span my-current-time="format"></span>
```

Look at the "Writing Directives (short version)" on this page: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive